# Button properties greyed out

Tags: android, eclipse, button, properties

I'm using eclipse v22.2.1-833290 and I'm creating an android project. The properties for a button are greyed out. I want to amend the on click value. I've checked around and I've made sure that I'm using Android 1.6 or later as I understand that this is required for android:onClick.

My manifest file includes:

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

and in android Properties for the project I've got android 2.2 ticked.

The button's text value is editable but none of the other properties. How do I make my button's properties editable?

Comment: WHat happens if you just go into the xml itself and add `android:onClick="yourMethodName"`?

Comment: Also, largely unrelated, but I would highly recommend setting your target SDK and the Android SDK in your project properties to 19, the most recent Android release.